# View rails4 db log on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a heroku app running (in production environment) on cedar stack. It uses postgres db.

In my environment/productions.rb file I have commented out this line

```
# config.log_level = :info
```

And in Heroku I have this config

```
$> heroku config
=== xxxx Config Vars
LOG_LEVEL:                    debug
RAILS_ENV:                    production
```

I want to view all db query that gets executed. In development environment locally I can see logs like this:

```
User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = 'xyz@gmail.com'   AND "users"."ustatus" IN (10, 11) LIMIT 1
```

But on `heroku logs` they never appear. Anyone know how to enable db log on heroku?

Answer (score 1):

Edit: I just found out why heroku does not display query logs when they should based on your production. rb configuration. The problem is queries will not be displayed by heroku if you have a so-called hobby tier plan.  You are probably using the free version, which would explain why your queries are not displayed. If you would upgrade to a standard or medium plan the heroku logs will show the performed queries.

This heroku article explicitly says no postgres logs are displayed at hobby tier level: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-plans#hobby-tier

Comment: Did you downvote? If so, could you please elaborate.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the log from rails console on heroku by running below commands:

```
$ heroku run rails c
File.open('log/production.log', 'r').each_line { |line| puts line }
```

As I found here

[heroku - how to see all the logs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2671454/heroku-how-to-see-all-the-logs)

Also here is heroku logging documentation:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging

Comment: this does not work. Even in that SO, you can see one comment is written as it is not working now. That SO question's answer is old and not relevant any more. This is now not working on cedar stack.

Comment: usually I will look my logs by adding --tail in heroku logs command that is $> 'heroku logs --tail'

Comment: Sumit, if you read my question carefully, then you will find, I am asking for Db logs. That does not show up in `heroku logs -t`

Comment: @jvk, here you go..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8031007/how-to-increase-heroku-log-drain-verbosity-to-include-all-rails-app-details

Answer (score 0):

Do everything by yourself:

```
  heroku run bash
```