# problems deploying sinatra app to heroku

Tags: ruby, heroku, sinatra

Ive just tried deploying a basic sinatra app to heroku and everytime i try and access the app through heroku i keep getting the following error messages in the heroku logs

> 2016-10-14T14:34:12.243266+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=sleepy-fjord-82689.herokuapp.com request_id=4e85cc9f-a2e2-4dc4-bbb6-8daa9de6778b fwd="82.5.195.102" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
>
> 2016-10-14T14:34:13.108228+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=sleepy-fjord-82689.herokuapp.com request_id=c173f495-e2f9-4119-8e45-790e2f55fc6e fwd="82.5.195.102" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=

Im new to heroku so I havent really got a clue why this is happening, any help pointing me in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you doing a `heroku restart`?

Comment: this error you're showing is totally generic; it tells us very little about what's actually causing the problem. That's not your fault; unfortunately, that's the default for Heroku logs. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8031007/how-to-increase-heroku-log-drain-verbosity-to-include-all-rails-app-details) to increase the logging level. A good way to debug this situation is to call `heroku run rails c` - if there's an error, it will be shown instead of this generic "App Crashed" message.

Answer (score 0):

Your application is crashing when navigating to the root ('/').  First make sure the app works on local machine, then follow the [rack app guide](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rack) for Heroku.  There's a section for Sinatra.  If this doesn't work, makes sure you can deploy the Hello World app as shown the in the example correctly.

Comment: Thans zlu. I thought it was something to do with that. It runs fine locally and can access the root directory fine but doesn't on heroku. Ive seen some people mentioning dynos when they were having similar problems, could it be something to do with that?

Answer (score 0):

Can you post here your Procfile file and your config.ru please?

if you want to check that your Procfile is working, you can check it locally with the `foreman` gem . Basically you need to add foreman to your development group in Gemfile and you can create a Procfile file with this content:

`web: bundle exec rackup -p $PORT`

And start your application with command `foreman start`.

Also to show in logs the full backtrace of the error, please consider adding to your Gemfile the gem `rails_12factor` and make sure that is available in the production group also.

This should allow you to see at least the full backtrace of the error.  Hope this helps you.

Note: Sinatra does not reload the application locally upon changes. If you want that, i would suggest you to use the `rerun` gem and the `rb-fsevent` gems in your development group, and a different Procfile for the development environment.

Example: Procfile.dev 

`web: rerun -- bundle exec rackup -p $PORT`

and run it locally with `foreman start -f Procfile.dev` . This will allow you to change code and see the changes without manually restarting the server everytime.

Hope this helps you at least find the erorr.